# disabling buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have four buttons with button2 as id.

> document.getElementById('button2').disabled=true;

With the above code, Only one button is disabled. I want all buttons to be disabled.

Any ideas.
Thank you.

Comment: ID is short for identifier. You should only use it once per page, or you must expect it not to work as expected.

Comment: You should use different ids for different elements. Alternatively, use a class and retrieve the elements by  `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: _I have four buttons with button2 as id._ That's your problem, `id`s are supposed to be unique (as in, one per element).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have four buttons with button2 as id.

Don't do that, [it's invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). `id` values **must** be unique in the document.

Instead, perhaps give them the same `class`:

```
<input type="button" class="button2">
<input type="button" class="button2">
<input type="button" class="button2">
<input type="button" class="button2">
```

Then on [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) you can do this:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".button2");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].disabled = true;
}
```

That works on current versions of, well, nearly everything. It doesn't work on IE7 and earlier. If you need to support those, I recommend using a decent DOM manipulation library (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries)), which will have the ability to look up elements by class.

---

Alternately, you can give them the same `name` and use the older `getElementsByName`, which is on even IE6 and IE7:

```
<input type="button" name="button2">
<input type="button" name="button2">
<input type="button" name="button2">
<input type="button" name="button2">
```

Then much the same loop:

```
var list = document.getElementsByName("button2");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].disabled = true;
}
```

But there are a couple of caveats to using `name` for this:

1. If this is in a `form`, while it would be fine in this case to do this because these are *buttons*, you may not want to use `name` for this in the general case. If you use the same `name` for multiple text fields or select boxes, for instance, you have to be sure you handle that right on the server-side when you receive the repeated field names.
2. Similarly, while fine for this use, `name` is only a valid attribute on form fields, not other kinds of elements. So again while okay for buttons, you don't want to generalize it.
3. Be careful not to use `"button2"` as an `id` on that same page, because IE8 and earlier have a bug in them that will make it act like that element has the `name` `"button2"` even though it doesn't. It's the same bug I talk about [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) in relation to `getElementById`.

So in general, `class` is probably the better way to go.

Comment: you can do the same with the `name` property and then `getElementsByName` this is the right answer.

Comment: @abc123: Yeah, I was commenting on your answer when you deleted it (saying "@theotheruser This is a perfectly acceptable use case for `name`") and asking you: What's the support like for `getElementsByName`?

Comment: it is usable in all browsers even IE since 5.5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: @abc123: Yeah, was just experimenting. Sadly, it's broken in IE8 and earlier (the [same way `getElementById` is](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html)), but that can be worked around by avoiding using the same string for names and IDs: http://jsbin.com/orahez/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/orahez/1)).

Comment: If this is occurring in a form, you wouldn't want 4 inputs with the same `name` attribute (unless they were checkboxes or radio buttons in a group).

Comment: @talemyn: It's fine for buttons (since they aren't submitted with the form; if they were submit buttons, only the one actually clicked would be submitted with the form). You're absolutely correct it wouldn't be fine for, say, text fields unless you expected to deal with that correctly server-side (which a lot of people do; it's not uncommon to deal with receiving multiple fields with the same name). I'll add a note.

Comment: Yeah, I know that technically it would work . . . just didn't want to be encouraging people to start a habit of using duplicate `name` values in forms.  :)  Even with buttons, if nothing else, it alters the ability reference individual form elements using the `document.form_name.input_name` approach.

Answer (score 0):

There should only be 1 occurence of an id value on a single page. Use different id values for each button (e.g., use id="button1" for one button, and id="button2" for the other button.

Then you can disable each of the buttons, one at a time:

```
document.getElementById('button1').disabled=true;
document.getElementById('button2').disabled=true;
```